# Improve Windows's batch script performance

Tags: windows, batch-file, command-prompt

I want to delete specific lines from text files, using this command:

```
for /f "delims=" %%d in ('"dir <Dir_Path> /a /b /s | sort"') do type %%d | findstr /V <String_To_Delete>  >  <%%d_Filtered.txt>
```

It is working but very very slow.
How can I improve the command or make it use in multi  cores?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the command line you've posted, the slowest parts are probably `findstr`, `sort`, and cmd's pipeline management.

- `findstr` is the big hit.  It needs to read and each entire file, but it's the whole reason for the exercise.  If you don't need the regular expression support, you can speed it up a little bit by using literal search strings and the `/L` parameter to disable regex support.  If possible, try to pre-filter your file list to reduce the amount of data that `findstr` has to parse.
- `sort` in your command line does nothing but change the order in which you process files, but to do so, it needs to read the entire file list into memory and run a sort algorithm on them.  Unless you have a specific reason the files have to be processed in alphabetical order by directory/filename, I would skip this step.
- You are probably losing some performance by reading the filename with `type` and then running the data through the CMD pipeline.  It may be faster to simply have `findstr` read the file directly, instead of using STDIN.

Using the suggestions above, your command line becomes

```
for /f "delims=" %%d in ('"dir <Dir_Path> /a /b /s"') do findstr /V /L [Literal_String] %%d  >  [%%d_Filtered.txt]
```

*Note that when optimizing, you should always measure your performance with a tool such as `timethis.exe`, rather than just accepting the word of some guy on a website.*

Comment: I think telling `findstr` explicitly whether the search string is a regular expression by `/R` or a literal string by `/L` could also help a bit; or in the latter case, to go for `find` instead...

Comment: Thanks @aschipfl.  I included the /L suggestion.